# Subscription call 2 times, how to unsubscribe observable in RxSwift

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift, subscription

Reset password call occurs 2 times, how can I remove the subscription in that block.

```
        let digits = [firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit, fifthDigit, sixthDigit]
        let digitsValid = digits.map { $0?.textField.rx.text.orEmpty.map({ $0.count == 1 }).share(replay: 1) }
        let allDigitsFilled = Observable.combineLatest(digitsValid.map{ $0 ?? BehaviorRelay(value: false).asObservable()}).share(replay: 1)
        allDigitsFilled.subscribe (onNext: { [weak self] (boolArray) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let isFilled = boolArray.allSatisfy({ $0 })
            if isFilled {
                self.viewModel.resetPassword()
            } 
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onNext block will be called every time any of the text fields changes its contents. Your first goal should be to make it so the block is only called when you want to reset the password.

So first, you want to put the `.allSatisfy` inside an Observable.filter call so your onNext block will only be called when all six text fields contain exactly 1 character. Once you do that, then you can simply use `.take(1)` which will complete the subscription once a next value is emitted.

Something like this should do it, and looks quite a bit cleaner:

```
let digits = [firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit, fifthDigit, sixthDigit]
let texts = digits.compactMap { $0?.textField.rx.text.orEmpty }
Observable.combineLatest(texts)
    .filter { $0.allSatisfy { $0.count == 1 } }
    .map { _ in }
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [viewModel] in
        viewModel?.resetPassword()
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Any idea about changing the first responder if a text field is filled? (in order)

Comment: Yes, each textField has to listen to the previous one and become first responder when it sees that the previous one has data. This sounds like a different question though. Either ask a new question (be sure to search first) or you could join the RxSwift slack (http://slack.rxswift.org)